# Cannot determine loading status in Google Maps

Tags: selenium, google-maps, selenium-chromedriver

I had a test written in Java and Selenium that basically does a search for a provider.  It then clicks on the provider's *Map This Location* link and opens a google map.  I would wait for an xpath visibility for that map after switching to the new window.

The URL would be something like

https://www.google.com/maps/dir//945+N+12th+St,+Milwaukee,+WI+53233/@43.0426642,-87.9297109,17z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x88051979232b79cd:0x905e19b746c46eb3!2m2!1d-87.9275222!2d43.0426642

This has been working fine for a year.  Today we got updated to Chrome version Version 74.0.3729.108 (Official Build) (64-bit) so we replaced our old Chromedriver (which was now giving us an error that the Chrome version had to be between 70 and 73) with 74.0.3729.6 which our head developer downloaded from the site.

The problem is, now, and only for certain addresses, I get that error
*unknown error: cannot determine loading status from no such execution context*

Some Stack Overflow items suggested

```
 1. Updating the Chrome Driver
 2. Using a longer timeout
```

as you can see from above we updated our chromedriver to be consistent with the version of Chrome.  I also updated the timeout to 300 seconds (5 minutes), but all in vain.

I am out of ideas about what else could be causing the problem.  The xpath I waited for was *//div[@aria-label='Map']* but I have tried other xpaths now too, such as "//div[@id='streetviewcard']".  I verified that the window I switched to was driver.getWindowHandles().get(1).  I had saved the original handle so I could switch back.  I looked at all the window handles, and there were only 2, the original one and the one I switched to.

No other searches come up with anything useful.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace

Comment: Probably company confidential?  I tried a different wait which seems to work.  The original one was a bit indirect.  Or it could have been a fluke, but I don't really believe in flukes.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't believe in _flukes_ that's why I wanted to see your _code trials_ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly the same error, moving to v74.

Something must have changed with chromedriver, or chrome - I assume that when a new tab is opened, execution continues sooner than it did before.   It's hard to tell what's actually changed, but ultimately I fixed our issues with a sleep:

Also, it's worth noting that getWindowHandles() returns in an undefined order - so might need some extra handling depending on your use case.

https://github.com/dvsa/mot-automated-testsuite/compare/ops-OPSTEAM-2827-selenium#diff-1fa0893dd1ad67d9c1a4ee1e777c20cb

Comment: they discourage using sleep(), but sometimes you have to